# Sencha touch IndexBar - get tapped index value

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

[image]
Am using indexbar in my contact list. I have a list of more than 100 contact so am using pagination plugin to display the contacts. my problem is when a user tap on index B i have to call an api to get the contacts starting from letter B, i dont know how to get the tapped index value.. please help me to solve this issue.. I dont have much code to paste..

```
list = Ext.create('Ext.dataview.List', Ext.Object.merge({
                itemTpl: itemTpl,
                id:'ctsitemheighttest',
                variableHeights: true,
                itemHeight : 'auto',
                scrollToTopOnRefresh: false,
                indexBar    : true,
                indexBar: {
                    itemId:'ctsindex',
                    id:'ctsindex',
                    margin:1,
                    handler:function(){
                        console.log('index tapped'); // can i do this way? its not working
                    }

                },
}
```

Please help me..thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this like the following way 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.IndexBar-event-index

```
list = Ext.create('Ext.dataview.List', Ext.Object.merge({
                    itemTpl: itemTpl,
                    id:'ctsitemheighttest',
                    variableHeights: true,
                    itemHeight : 'auto',
                    scrollToTopOnRefresh: false,
                    indexBar    : true,
                    indexBar: {
                        //letters: ['N','T','B','D','C','K','M','L','O','S'].sort(),
                        itemId:'ctsindex',
                        id:'ctsindex',
                        margin:1,
                        listeners: {
                            index: function (html, target, eOpts) {
                                //console.log('inside indexbar',target);


                            } // tap


                        }

                    }
```

Comment: How could I add this `indexBar` listener in my controller ?

Comment: @AbhijitMuke 
You can do the following way 
config: {
        refs: {

            ctsindexbartap:'#ctsindex'

        },
        control: {
           
            ctsindexbartap:{
                index:'onCtsIndexBarTap'
            }

        }
    },
 onCtsIndexBarTap:function(html, target, eOpts){
 console.log(target);
 }